# Where I can found the css in https://websitedomain.com/?gt3_show_only_css=1&ver=5.4.1 of wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am newbie to WordPress and currently working to get an idea on how WordPress works. Now when I visit a new page url like something this:

```
mysite.com/my_newly_created_page
```

and inspect its CSS, I found style of the content is controlled from here:

```
mysite.com/?gt3_show_only_css=1&ver=5.4.1
```

I want to get the css or part of any css which is gt3_show_only_css but can't understand how to locate it from the url as you can see this is query to the main url of the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always find the WordPress CSS files in your theme at
"/wp-content/themes/your-theme/style.css" or in a subfolder of your theme like for example "assets" .

Also the different plugins bring their own CSS files. 
If you just want to make simple changes to the CSS code, you can do this in your child theme in the style.css file or directly in WordPress:
Appearance -> Customize -> Additional CSS

Here you can define separate instructions for each CSS class.